setup-node pnpm node_modules location
I'm still having this problem, which is fine in development — I just manually create a symlink in the top-level node_modules. However, I'm now trying to integrate linting into my GitHub CI actions, and so need to be able to create the symlink on the build created by actions/setup-node.
Where does actions/setup-node put node_modules when doing a pnpm install?
I tried just doing what I do locally, assuming that it's installed in whatever the cwd for the runner is:
name: 'Intall'
description: 'Sets up the repository'
inputs:
  node-version: # node version on which to build
    description: "Node version for the build"
    required: true
    default: 'latest'
runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Set up pnpm
      # pnpm version controlled in top level package.json
      uses: pnpm/action-setup@v4
    - name: Install NodeJS
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: ${{ inputs.node-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      shell: bash
      run: pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
    # pnpm doesn't do this? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    # needed for linting
    - name: Link globals package
      shell: bash
      run: ln -s node_modules/.pnpm/globals@15.6.0/node_modules/globals/ node_modules/globals

But that ln fails. Based on this answer (which is really about npm ci, not setup-node and pnpm, but I figured I'd give it a try), I tried switching to ~/.npm:
      run: ln -s ~/.npm/node_modules/.pnpm/globals@15.6.0/node_modules/globals/ ~/.npm/node_modules/globals

But still no love:
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/runner/.npm/node_modules/globals': No such file or directory
The setup-node docs say, "The action ... caches global cache on the machine instead of node_modules", but that seems to be referring to the global which doesn't seem right; and even if it is, it doesn't say where it caches it.
I also tried digger a little deeper into the GitHub Actions output, and it says
  env:
    PNPM_HOME: /home/runner/setup-pnpm/node_modules/.bin

But AFAICT from search the web, PNPM_HOME is only where pnpm itself is stored, not the installed packages.
Where is actions/setup-node and/or pnpm/action-setup putting the local node_modules, such that I can create the missing symlink to <node_modules>/.pnpm/node_modules/globals@15.6.0/node_modules/globals?

It turns out you can get the path with github.workspace, so this ended up working:
    - name: Link globals package
      shell: bash
      run: ln -s ${{ github.workspace }}/node_modules/.pnpm/globals@15.6.0/node_modules/globals/ ${{ github.workspace }}/node_modules/globals

